# calendar with events javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calendar

i need to create a calendar which a person can add events like a school test in he next week, i searched alot and couldnt find what im looking for, this is what i got so far [calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fiAH.png)

```
<div id="calendar" class="fc-calendar-container"></div>
```

and i want to add like two input texts one which shows the date and the other the person inserts the event and changes the color of the day that has a event and when they click the day it shows the event